# How to display Public groups in table format list in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, public-group

How to display Public groups in table format list and in select one public group,then search button clicks need to display table format list the group members in particular public group? anybody help me......

Answer (score 0):

You could use this SOQL statement in you controller

Select Id, Name, Type, DeveloperName,RelatedId
From Group 
WHERE RelatedId = NULL

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the public groups first.
2. From the groups selected, select all users that have their Ids in the `GroupMember` table, where Group ID is in the first query list result.
3. Display the groups and users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more information about custom list controllers:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question already.. This might be helpful for you.. Check this question..

> visualforce page? - [How to display public group users,when i had given group name in search bar need to display the users to particular group name in visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/96882/24809)
>   search bar need to display the users to particular group name in visualforce page? - [How to display public group users,when i had given group name in search bar need to display the users to particular group name in visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/96882/24809)

Comment: My requirement is I want table format for after select the one public group then display the group members in the form of table format First display the all public groups picklist format then
 we are select one user Now How to display the group members in the form of table format.

Comment: That is what built in the link I shared with you.. There public group is searched from the text search which then later I provided the solution to convert in a picklist with list of public groups available ...

Comment: Explore that code .. I'll post the final code to use picklist instead of search box tomorrow...